# Pandas: Cannot import rolling_mean

Tags: python, pandas, gpx

I am trying to parse some coordinates using gpxpy and [this](https://ocefpaf.github.io/python4oceanographers/blog/2014/08/18/gpx/) project, but when trying to import `smoo1` from `oceans` library I encounter this error: 
`from pandas import rolling_mean
ImportError: cannot import name 'rolling_mean'`
I have tried to read about this error and fix it, but as far as I understood the library tries to import a function that was depreciated. I am not sure about what to do in a situation like this one.
I am using python 3.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rolling_*` functions have been deprecated in favour of the new [`Rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) APIs.

```
df['column'].rolling(window=x).mean()
```

Comment: How can I import it?

Comment: @roberto.sannazzaro You don't. It's a bound method of DataFrame and Series objects. I gave you an example right there

Comment: You import it with the statement:
`from pandas.core.window import Rolling`